# Run Snow Leopard (non-server version) as guest in Lion

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, vmware-fusion

I know you can run the server version, but neither my Lion (current) or my Snow Leopard CD I have is the server version.
Is it possible to run Snow Leopard as guest in Lion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allowed to run Snow Leopard Server and Lion in a virtual machine (of course, that doesn't mean it will be easy!), but not Snow Leopard. That is, according to the EULA — it's probably *possible* to do this ([this blog post](http://blog.iharder.net/2011/07/25/run-snow-leopard-in-virtual-machine-to-retain-powerpc-applications/) will help you out there) — but to be compliant with the EULA, you shouldn't.